How to switch active chain in wagmi for WalletConnect wallet
Working on web3 app (js) that supports multiple chains, and before minting on specific chain it uses wagmi useSwitchNetwork hook to request wallet to switch the chain. It works fine with browser extension wallets, but not in WalletConnect mobile wallets.
In Rainbow Mobile it fails with Missing or invalid. request() method: wallet_switchEthereumChain ticket, it does not even have a concept of the active chain anywhere on UI.
Any ideas on how to get it resolved it or where to ask?
Update:
it looks like it's a problem with testnets only, so Rainbow Mobile cannot switch to testnets

the problem is caused by Rainbow mobile wallet not supporting any testnets (at the moment). It's actually able to switch to other mainets, but not to the testnet (Base Sepolia) I was using for testing

I have the almost the same problem, I use wagmi/walletConnect, I have 2 chains and when user is connected and I'm trying to switch chain, it switches but in background and doesnt reflect in wallet, so no any transaction will appear in my wallet... do you have any workaround about that?

@ArmanGhazaryan make sure that useNetwork returns the desired chainId before starting a transaction
